# How to do context-sensitive matching with the pattern system?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, rule, regular-expressions

In Perl RegEx, we have the [look-ahead/behind](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html.en?source=footer#:%7E:text=lookahead%2Flookbehind) feature; it there a similar functionality available for Wolfram Language patterns?

---

Re [@mikado](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36788/mikado):

- Suppose we have a random expression in `FullForm`, something like (do forgive me for writing this like lousy json):

```
H[
  <<something>>,
  l0,
  h1[
    h12[l121], 
  ],
  h2[
    h21[],  
    h22[l221, l222]
  ],
  h3[
    l31,  
    h32[l221, l222]
  ],
  <<something>>
]
```

where I would hope to select (restricted to the first level) all the cases of `Sequence[h1[___],h2[h21[],___]]` between a `l1` and a `h3[_,h32[__]]`. What's the way to do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of an expression you would like to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matching you're looking for in this case is via `SequenceCases`, I think, which represents a subsequence to match as a list—so, for example, `SequenceCases[{a,a,b,c,b}, {_,b}]` extracts `{{a,b}, {c,b}}`.

But, you can also wrap your pattern in a rule which will match the lhs and replace it with the rhs. The standard way to implement "matching environments" like look-aheads and look-behinds in Mathematica (as far as I'm aware) is to use a rule of the form `{preceding : <patt0>, p : <extractedpatt>, following : <patt1>} :> p`. This essentially matches the full sequence (including the look ahead/behind pattern) and then replaces it with what's in the middle.

`SequenceCases` also requires that the head of the to-be-extracted-from expression is `List`. So:

```
SequenceCases[List @@ H[<...>],
    {l0, p : PatternSequence[h1[___],h2[h21[],___]], h3[_,h32[__]]} :> {p}]
```

This should give a list of subsequences that are matched enclosed by `List`, i.e. something like `{{h1[<...>], h2[h21[],<...>]}, {h1[<...>], h2[h21[],<...>]}, <...>}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've used `SequenceCases` before, but it didn't occur to me that it could be used as such. I come to realize that the patterns of MMA is as expressive for S-exprs as regex is for strings (which must have been obvious for a wiser man).

Comment: Btw I'm a little unsatisfied with WRI's naming. Maybe it would be more accurate to tern `SequenceCases[]` and related functions as `Splice*[]`, as they require wrapping the actual pattern with `{}` and only works with `List`s, conforming to the syntax and semantics of `Splice`.